# how to mount a local volume for my docker?

Tags: python, linux, docker, jupyter-notebook

i am newbie to the Linux and docker. I am using the below command to run the docker:

```
sudo nvidia-docker run --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -it -v /home/pyman/PEYMAN:??????? 21bbc6c8f7ed
```

where; `/home/pyman/PEYMAN` is my local directory

and `21bbc6c8f7ed` is the image ID.

after running this command, the workspace root changes to `root@0ce2ee24bac0:/workspace#`

then I type `jupyter notebook` and run it, and it provides two links which only the second link opens the jupyter notebook in the browser.

```
http://hostname:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxx
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

but I dont know what is my `container_dir` in the first command to put in `?????`, and how to get the directory. is the container_dir the same directory that jupyter is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `container_dir` is the path inside the container, where you'd like to see your mounted files. The directory inside container does not even have to exist, yon can pick almost any place to mount your files. If you work with `jupyter`, it makes sense to add your files to the working directory:

```
docker run -v /home/pyman/PEYMAN:/workspace/myfiles
```

Once inside the container you will find `/home/pyman/PEYMAN` in `/workspace/myfiles`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. that worked very well. However I dont understand why when I try to open a file within my code, it still gives an error.
for example: when I run this code `a = open('/home/pyman/PEYMAN/test.txt', 'r')`
I get this error: `No such file or directory: '/home/pyman/PEYMAN/test.txt'`

Comment: In the container, the path to the file is /workspace/files/test.txt